# IIS 7 Rewriting not working

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have some rewrite rules that were working with a IIS rewrite tool for IIS 6, but now I have ported them to IIS 7 rewrite. Here is the rule:

```
Pattern:
/resource/(.*)/.*

Action URL:
/index.cfm?go=resources&details=1&rid={R:1}
```

Before it was rewriting it correctly now it is hijacking all of the images for example:
/resources/assets/images/gopic.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this, you may use IIS 7 Rewrite Module.

You may find some useful information about it from the below article :

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Also, I have just blogged about it with an example implementation. It might help as well :

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/remove-trailing-slash-from-the-urls-of-your-asp-net-web-site-with-iis-7-url-rewrite-module